# Magento - backend - error in trying to view order

Tags: php, mysql, magento, memcached

When I want to view an order in my Magento-shop (backend), I get this error:

Notice: Undefined index: percent  in /home/users/[username]/[domain]/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/totals/tax.phtml on line 40

It's a new error, this didn't use to happen.
I've not installed any extensions lately (after installing the latest extension everything still worked).

The development-server doesn't have this problem. The only difference between live and development is that the live server uses memcached, while the development server doesn't. (development has the latest files, so does live. The development DB is a fresh copy of the live DB)

I've already cleared the cache on the live server, but the problem doesn't go away.

Comment: Maybe development server has different error reporting level? Since this error states about notice.

Comment: Cleared the cache - which one? Memcache persists even if you've cleared the usual Mage caches, files, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This only shows up:

- for orders containing configurable products
- if the configuration option sales -> tax -> orders display settings -> display full tax summary is ON
- if your PHP error reporting settings are such that notices are displayed

It was fixed in Magento 1.7.

Answer (score -2):

Look in index.php and change

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

to

```
error_reporting(0);
```

That should hide the notice but will also hide (possibly) important notices also.

Comment: Error suppression is not a solution. It's not even a bandaid. Even in a production environment, errors should be logged for resolution, not simply silenced. Downvote for suggesting error silencing without resolving.

Comment: I did mention that this solution would hide important errors. A little harsh to downvote perhaps...

Comment: With reference to the OP's question - regarding Magento specifically, this would qualify as one of those "important notices" in my book: undefined index 'percent' with tax, where Mage is commonly known to be error-prone and buggy.

Comment: It's a notice level error. If everything works then as Ivan stated it's probably got different error settings on the new server.

Comment: The error level is "just a notice" which can crash the application when this particular app gets to the cart. But if the most significant / meaningful characteristic to you is the error's level, I doubt I can help further.